# Margin transition effect in scrollable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, infinite-scroll

I would like to achieve a "rubber" effect: like when we scroll past the limit, and the scroll element scroll "over" the limit a bit.

So I thought about having CSS transition in the margin. The `margin-top` transition works as I expected. But the `margin-bottom` should "push the element up", so we see its lower border be pushed. Right now it looks like the scrollable element gets longer, but not "pushed up".

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const scrollWrapper = document.getElementById('scrollWrapper');
const scrollChild = scrollWrapper.children[0];
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
const topBtn = buttons[0];
const bottomBtn = buttons[1];

topBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollWrapper.scrollTop = 0; // so it goes up and show the effect
  scrollChild.style.marginTop = '20px';
  setTimeout(() => scrollChild.style.marginTop = '0px', 2000);
});

bottomBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollWrapper.scrollTop = scrollWrapper.scrollHeight; // so it goes down and show the effect
  scrollChild.style.marginBottom = '20px';
  setTimeout(() => scrollChild.style.marginBottom = '0px', 2000);
});
```

```css
#scrollWrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 130px;
}

section {
  margin: 10px;
}

section>div {
  margin: 0px;
  transition: margin .7s ease;
  height: 1000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient( red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<section id="scrollWrapper">
  <div></div>
</section>
<section>
  <button>Top margin</button>
  <button>Bottom margin</button>
</section>
```

I could force it with JavaScript ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17bp94a9/)) but that feels wrong. I feel its a CSS detail I did not understand enough.

Comment: You're gonna need some sort of scrolling velocity, otherwise this effect wont make sense. I'll try to come up with something, but first I'd need to know if this should work with touchscreens aswell?

Comment: Hi @ManuelOtto I will use this in touch, yes. But that is not my main concern, that part I can achieve, just wanted to nail down the problem with the effect. If you have possibility to post a example would be great.